# How to use ActiveMQ in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, activemq-classic

I'm building a Meteor application that needs to receive JMS or AMQP messages, process them, and store the results in Meteor's MongoDB. I want this all to happen on the server, not the client.

I read the ActiveMQ AJAX [page](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html) and that seems like a promising lead, but I don't know how to get it working. I was hoping to just create a new .js file in my project's server folder and put all the code in there, but creating the ActiveMQ AJAX servlet and importing the ActiveMQ javascript files seems to require HTML tags. Also, does AciveMQ need to be running for the servlet to work?

I'm new to web development.

Comment: When you say you: "want this all to happen on the server, not the client." You mean you want this to happen on your Meteor server correct? You are attempting to call a queuing server and getting the AMQP messages and processing them on the Meteor server, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at node-amqp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp). It should slip nicely into a meteor project and give you the functionality you are looking for. Once you install it and require it, you should be able to connect to your message server, create a queue, receive messages into the queue, and then it's just up to you to process them and store them to your mongo.

Comment: I like that. It so happens my message server uses AMQP 1.0 and node-amqp only supports 0.9.1. I found [amqp10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp10) that supports 1.0.

It can be installed with meteorhacks:npm meteor package. There is [documentation](https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10/tree/master/api) but I'm not clear if my URI's are correctly formatted.

    client.connect("amqp://username:password@hostip:hostport", function(connError) {
    client.receive("topic://topicname", function(rxError, payload, annotation) {
    doStuff()
    })
    });

Comment: I think that should do it. I would definitely add some error checking and handling and a few test cases. But otherwise I do believe it will work.